# Access conditional required fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating a form that allows users to enter scores 1-5 for given categories In this example, On_Time_Payment). For each category, a score of 3 or less must have an explaination in a comment field (In this case, On_Time_Payment_Comments). I am trying to write something that will force the user to enter something if the value of On_Time_Payment is below 4; however, what I have right now is allowing any scores to pass with nothing in the comment field.

```
   Private Sub On_Time_Payment_Comments_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    If On_Time_Payment.Value < 4 Then
        If Len(On_Time_Payment_Comments) > 0 Then
        End If
        Else
            MsgBox "The value you entered for On Time Payment is 3 or less."
            Cancel = True
            On_Time_Payment_Comments.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Similar Question is also posted here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982107/]

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub On_Time_Payment_Comments_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    If On_Time_Payment.Value < 4 Then
        MsgBox "The value you entered for On Time Payment is 3 or less."
        If Len(On_Time_Payment_Comments) = 0 Then
            Cancel = True
            On_Time_Payment_Comments.SetFocus
        Else
            MsgBox On_Time_Payment_Comments, vbokonly, "Len: " & len(On_Time_Payment_Comments)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, that now skips the message box even when OTP.Value < 4. I double checked that nothing was in the OTP_Comments field. Could this have something to do with the event selection?

Comment: Yes, that works much better. For some reason it's not setting focus to OTP_Comments, though. Still trying to determine what's going on with that. Tried changing event to LostFocus with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Your original answer was relatively close to what you needed, but I think you lost track of the If-Else-End If structure.  Here is what I think you want:

```
`Private Sub On_Time_Payment_Comments_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

    If On_Time_Payment.Value < 4 Then

        If (Len(On_Time_Payment_Comments) <= 0 Or IsNull(On_Time_Payment_Comments)) Then
            MsgBox "The value you entered for On Time Payment is 3 or less."
            Cancel = True
            On_Time_Payment_Comments.SetFocus
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was something going on with the naming and properties of the fields vs text boxes on the forms. This is now working:

```
Private Sub On_Time_Payment_Comments_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
   If On_Time_Payment.Value < 4 Then
    If IsNull(On_Time_Payment_Comments) Then
        MsgBox "The score you entered for On Time Payment is less than 4. Please provide an explaination in the comment field."
        Cancel = True
        On_Time_Payment_Comments.SetFocus
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Thank you all that helped with this!