# Make Fileds compulsory if a particular filed is filled in Access Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form in access, where I want to make 3 fields (`FYear`, `cboPeriodicity`, `cboPeriod`) compulsory if another field `cboCompliance` is filled in by user.

I have tried the below code, where I am canceling save, if any of these fields are Empty. And also giving error message through `msgBox`

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Form_BeforeUpdate_Err

'Audit Data Values Set
Me.LastModifiedBy.Value = [TempVars]![currentUserID]
Me.LastModifiedTime.Value = Now()

'If Compliance value is filled, make other vaules compulsory
If IsNull(Me.cboCompliance.Value) Or Len(Me.cboCompliance.Value) <= 0 Then
    'DO nothing
Else
    Dim txtFiledisEmpty As String
    Dim wantToCancel As Boolean

    'Finiancial year ending
    If IsNull(Me.FYear.Value) Then
        wantToCancel = True
        txtFiledisEmpty = "If Compliance is selected, FY ENDING cannot be blank" & char(10)
        Me.FYear.SetFocus

    End If
    'Periodicity
    If IsNull(Me.cboPeriodicity.Value) Then
        wantToCancel = True
        txtFiledisEmpty = "If Compliance is selected, PERIODICITY cannot be blank" & char(10)
        Me.cboPeriodicity.SetFocus

    End If
    'Period
    If IsNull(Me.cboPeriod.Value) Then
        wantToCancel = True
        txtFiledisEmpty = "If Compliance is selected, PERIOD cannot be blank"
        Me.cboPeriod.SetFocus

    End If

    MsgBox "Error"
    Cancel = wantToCancel
End If

'Error Handling
Form_BeforeUpdate_Exit:
        Exit Sub
Form_BeforeUpdate_Err:
       MsgBox Error$
       Resume Form_BeforeUpdate_Exit

End Sub
```

I am unable to find (after an about hr of debugging), where the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint (click in the gray margin in the VBA code editor, which should display a red circle), attempt to close the form, and step through with the debugger (using F8)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I found my silly mistake.

Comment: Then post a description of that mistake as an answer, if you think it could be useful to someone else. If not, then delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

There was a silly mistake in my code. 
`Char` should have been `chr`

The code was modified a little, to better messages.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Form_BeforeUpdate_Err


'If Compliance value is filled, make other vaules compulsory
If IsNull(Me.cboCompliance.Value) Or Len(Me.cboCompliance.Value) <= 0 Then
    'DO nothing
Else
    Dim txtFiledisEmpty As String
    txtFiledisEmpty = "If Compliance is selected, " & Chr(10)
    Dim wantToCancel As Boolean
    wantToCancel = False

    'Period
    If IsNull(Me.cboPeriod.Value) Then
        wantToCancel = True
        txtFiledisEmpty = txtFiledisEmpty & " > PERIOD cannot be blank" & Chr(10)
        Me.cboPeriod.SetFocus
    End If

    'Periodicity
    If IsNull(Me.cboPeriodicity.Value) Then
        wantToCancel = True
        txtFiledisEmpty = txtFiledisEmpty & " > PERIODICITY cannot be blank" & Chr(10)
        Me.cboPeriodicity.SetFocus
    End If

    'Finiancial year ending
    If IsNull(Me.FYear.Value) Then
        wantToCancel = True
        txtFiledisEmpty = txtFiledisEmpty & " > FY ENDING cannot be blank" & Chr(10)
        Me.FYear.SetFocus
    End If

    If wantToCancel Then
        MsgBox txtFiledisEmpty
    End If

    Cancel = wantToCancel
End If

'Error Handling
Form_BeforeUpdate_Exit:
        Exit Sub
Form_BeforeUpdate_Err:
       MsgBox Error$
       Resume Form_BeforeUpdate_Exit

End Sub
```